# How to get all rows using a specific value in parameter

Tags: sql-server

Are there any way to get all rows in a where clause if a parameter have a specific value

Example if BoltPattern = ALL then it should return

```
|   BoltPattern | 
-----------------
|   5x117    | 
|   5x117    | 
|   5x120    | 
|   5x125    |
```

else if boltpattern = 5x117 then it should return

```
|   BoltPattern | 
-----------------
|   5x117    | 
|   5x117    |
```

My stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [Data].[usp_FilterData]
    @BoltPattern nvarchar(1000)=NULL,
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    SELECT
        P.[BoltPattern]
    FROM 
        [Data].[WheelData] P 
    WHERE 
        @BoltPattern IS NULL OR P.[BoltPattern] = @BoltPattern
```

Comment: did you cut something in stored procedure?  What is "WHERE @BoltPattern..."?

Comment: yes as this is a bigger procedure i only took thoose that are relating to my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to extract all the records WHEN @BoltPattern  IS NULL you can use:

```
WHERE  @BoltPattern IS NULL OR BoltPattern=@BoltPattern AND @BoltPattern IS NOT NULL
```

If you want to extract all the records WHEN @BoltPattern  ='ALL' you can use:

```
WHERE  @BoltPattern ='ALL' OR BoltPattern=@BoltPattern AND @BoltPattern <>'ALL'
```